# How can I see a user's articles in his joomla user profile?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, zoo, zoo-cck, cck

I hope the community can help me.
In this project, I would like to use Joomla's user profile view system and display the latest user posts.

I thought maybe it would be doable to create a layout in mod_zooitem and implement a ZOO user's most recent post views model and then enable this module in the user's profile so that if a user wants to see another user's content, can do it.

I have no idea how to apply for such a request, I hope you can help me.

Idea.

**/module/mod_itemzoo/mod_itenzoo.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package   ZOO Item
 * @author    YOOtheme https://yootheme.com
 * @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
 * @license   https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 only
 */

use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// load config
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_zoo/config.php');

// get app
$zoo = App::getInstance('zoo');

// load zoo frontend language file
$zoo->system->language->load('com_zoo');

// init vars
$path = dirname(__FILE__);

//register base path
$zoo->path->register($path, 'mod_zooitem');

if ($application = $zoo->table->application->get($params->get('application', 0))) {

    $items = $zoo->module->getItems($params);

    // set renderer
    $renderer = $zoo->renderer->create('item')->addPath(array($zoo->path->path('component.site:'), dirname(__FILE__)));

    $layout = $params->get('layout', 'default');

    include(ModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_zooitem', $params->get('theme', 'list')));
}
```

/modules/modules_zooitem/mod_zooitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.2" method="upgrade" client="site">
    <name>ZOO Item</name>
    <author>YOOtheme</author>
    <creationDate>August 2022</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH</copyright>
    <license>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 only</license>
    <assetsLicense>YOOtheme Proprietary Use License (https://yootheme.com/license)</assetsLicense>
    <authorEmail>info@yootheme.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>https://yootheme.com</authorUrl>
    <version>4.1.20</version>
    <description>Item module for ZOO developed by YOOtheme (https://yootheme.com)</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_zooitem">mod_zooitem.php</filename>
        <filename>changelog.php</filename>
        <filename>file.script.php</filename>
        <folder>fields</folder>
        <folder>renderer</folder>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
    </files>
    <scriptfile>file.script.php</scriptfile>
    <config>
        <fields name="params" >
            <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_zooitem/fields">
                <field name="theme" type="filename" default="" label="Theme" description="Visual style" path="/tmpl/" />
                <field name="layout" type="filename" default="" label="Layout" description="The Item Layout" path="/renderer/item/" />
                <field name="media_position" type="list" default="left" label="Media Position" description="MEDIAPOSITION_DESCRIPTION">
                    <option value="left">Left</option>
                    <option value="right">Right</option>
                    <option value="top">Top</option>
                    <option value="middle">Middle</option>
                    <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
                </field>
                <field name="application" type="zooapplication" default="" label="Items" description="APPLICATION_DESCRIPTION" categories="true" frontpage="true" items="true" types="true" />
                <field name="mode" type="hidden" label="" required="false" description="" />
                <field name="type" type="hidden" label="" required="false" description="" />
                <field name="category" type="hidden" label="" required="false" description="" />
                <field name="item_id" type="hidden" label="" required="false" description="" />
                <field name="subcategories" type="radio" default="0" label="Include Subcategories" description="SUBCATEGORY_DESCRIPTION">
                    <option value="0">JNO</option>
                    <option value="1">JYES</option>
                </field>
                <field name="count" type="text" default="4" size="5" label="Item Count" description="Maximum number of items to display" />
                <field name="order" type="zooitemorder" default="_itemname" label="Item Order" description="ITEM_ORDER" apps="true" random="true" />
                <field name="moduleclass_sfx" type="text" default="" label="Module Class Suffix" description="" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

/modules/mod_zooitem/tmpl/items_users.php

```
<?php


// no direct access
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

$css_class = $application->getGroup().'-'.$application->getTemplate()->name;

?>

<?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>

<ul class="uk-list uk-list-divider <?php echo $css_class ?>">
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $renderer->render('item.'.$layout, compact('item', 'params')); ?></li>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?php else : ?>
<?php echo Text::_('COM_ZOO_NO_ITEMS_FOUND'); ?>
<?php endif;
```

/modules/mod_zooitem/renderer/item/user_items.php

```
<?php


// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

$media_position = $params->get('media_position', 'top');

?>

<div class="layout-default <?php if ($media_position == 'top' || $media_position == 'middle' || $media_position == 'bottom') echo 'alignment-center'; ?>">

    <?php if (($media_position == 'top' || $media_position == 'left' || $media_position == 'right') && $this->checkPosition('media')) : ?>
    <div class="media media-<?php echo $media_position; ?>"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('media'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if ($this->checkPosition('title')) : ?>
    <p class="title"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('title'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if ($this->checkPosition('meta')) : ?>
    <p class="meta"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('meta', array('style' => 'comma')); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if (($media_position == 'middle') && $this->checkPosition('media')) : ?>
    <div class="media media-<?php echo $media_position; ?>"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('media'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if ($this->checkPosition('description')) : ?>
    <div class="description"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('description', array('style' => 'block')); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if (($media_position == 'bottom') && $this->checkPosition('media')) : ?>
    <div class="media media-<?php echo $media_position; ?>"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('media'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if ($this->checkPosition('links')) : ?>
    <p class="links"><?php echo $this->renderPosition('links', array('style' => 'pipe')); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I hope that the community can help me to achieve it since programming is not my field.

Comment: Hmm.  I see where `$searching` is accessed, but I don't see where it is declared.  I also see some incorrect string concatenation syntax when cinstructing `<li>` markup.  Do you have error reporting turned on and all the way up?  Part of asking a good, narrow, clear question is providing all necessary debugging details so that contributors have the easiest possible time assisting you.

Comment: @mickmackusa
I'm sorry, excuse me, I reformulated the query, I hope that now it will be more useful to you

Comment: Volunteer contributors and future researchers shouldn't need to download a .zip file to understand your question.  We'd prefer that all details are statically written as text in the question body (when reasonable). If you cannot narrow your question or you are actually looking for someone else to do your software development, then this community might not be the right place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, they help me build a solution. I do not intend to make any money from this implementation and I understand that by suggesting it in a public forum even less.
I also appreciate your defense towards the sector but I think it is not my case. You can sharpen knives elsewhere.

Comment: I might be asking something silly, but does `compact()` have access to the `$params` variable? https://3v4l.org/X0o2Z  `$media_position == 'top' || $media_position == 'left' || $media_position == 'right')` can be reduced to `in_array($media_position, ['top', 'left', 'right'])`  Is `$items` not an indexed array? Do you manually need to increment the counter or can you just declare `$i` as the key in the `foreach()` signature?  Where exactly does your script fail?  Are you able to access the desired data in the view template? or is the data not even available? Did you dump your variables out?

Comment: Do you manually need to increment the counter or can you just declare $i as the key in the foreach() signature?
--In this example it shows the total number of items of the app that you have basically created.
Where exactly does your script fail?
--This script does not fail, it is missing, this is a model that comes with zoo by default.
Only that the model that ZOO brings only extracts the content in a general way by applications or by categories that you can order, etc.
This is where I imagine introducing user options would be functional. show "my content" (that of the user).

Comment: Are you able to access the desired data in the view template?
--Yes, everything works as it should.
or is the data not even available? 
--Yes, If they are available when you create the module it asks you to select which applications you want the data from.
Did you dump your variables out?
--Nope.
This model is a default that the module brings, you can select among several, the one that they expose is one of them.

Comment: It is best to offer these details as an [edit] on your question.  The `foreach()` will increase `$i`.

Comment: Have you considered the Joomla core module, Articles Latest, that can display articles created, added or modified by the logged in user and displayed on their profile page, or any page really? Might be enough to provide you with what you want.

Comment: Hi @Irata, I had thought about it too, in fact it is what I need but:
The point is that in this project, all the content is created with ZOO CCK..